# ASP.NET/JavaScript - I'm trying to get an ImageButton onClick event to swap images

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i have a navigation bar made up of ImageButtons that have their image swapped out on mouse over and back on mouse out. i used this code in the Page_Load handler to do this:

```
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "this.src='mouseover.gif'")
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOut", "this.src='mouseout.gif'")
```

what i'm trying to do now is get the mouseover image to load when you click the button and are taken to the page. i tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "this.src='mouseover.gif'")
```

does anyone know how i can get this to work? thanks.

Comment: my guess is that my OnClick code doesn't work because of postback.
every time the button is clicked, the image is swapped out but then the page/button loads again and it goes back to it's original image. is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnClientClick

Comment: when you use OnClientClick, what does the generated HTML look like?